# How to get selected file name from file uploader(input=file) to model in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on bulk insert in MVC, I want to insert text fields and files(images).

I am getting files in HttpPostedFileBase[].

But in model it(Photo) shows null.

Model:-

```
 public partial class User_Image
    {
        public int SrNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

View:-

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
 {
     int j = 0;
     foreach (var i in Model)
    {
       <tr>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].SrNo, new { @Value = Session["SrNo"], @class = "currnent_srno", @readonly = "true" })</td>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Name, new { @required = "required", @class = "myclass" })</td>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Photo, new { type = "file", @class = "fileuploader", @required = "required" })</td>
       </tr>
    }
}
```

Controller Action:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BulkData(List<User_Image> ci, HttpPostedFileBase[] file, FormCollection fc)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (TestEntities dc = new TestEntities())
            {
                foreach (var i in ci)
                {
                    dc.User_Image.Add(i);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Data successfully saved!";
             }
         }
    }
```

jQuery:-  (to add name attr in all input files)

```
  $('input[type="file"]').attr('name', 'file');
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Its very unclear what you trying to do here. You never generate a form control for `Photo` so it will always be `null` in the POST method. Your uploading files but you never save them anywhere so they will be lost. Best guess is you want to save them to a file server and then save their file names in the database? In any case, edit you question to explain what your trying to do (almost everything your currently doing is anti-MVC and needs to be re-written)

Answer (score 0):

Model should be like this

```
public partial class User_Image
{
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string  Photo { get; set; }
}
```

And View should be like this

```
foreach (var i in Model)
{
   <tr>          
      <td>@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Photo, new { @class = "fileuploader", @required = "required" })</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" /></td>
  </tr>
}
```

And Control should be like this

```
public ActionResult BulkData(List<User_Image> ci, string Photo, FormCollection fc)
```

Please write javascript function to load convert filedata into base64 string on upload.

Comment: i am using the same model in other views as well isn't any other solution for this, bcoz in this case i have to change my other views .

Comment: even i also tried with this but its showing an error "System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcAppImageupload.Models.User_Image2>' does not contain a definition for 'Photo' and no extension method 'Photo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcAppImageupload.Models.User_Image2>"

Comment: Do one thing. Store the Image value as base64 string. Add one hidden control and write javascript function to assign base64 value it that input element. And you will get the string value in your controller. Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue and made an alternate way to solve this issue.

Rather than submitting attributes (in your case List) and image as parameter to action. Add them in formData object and pass that data to ajax call as below and get it in action and save them.

```html
                var formData = new FormData();
                var totalFiles = document.getElementById("attachFiles").files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                    var file = document.getElementById("attachFiles").files[i];

                    formData.append("attachFiles", file);
                }
                                               
                formData.append('SrNo', varsrno);
                formData.append('Name', varName);
                formData.append('Photo', varPhoto);

          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("BulkData", "Controller" )",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
                
        });
```

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult BulkData()
        {

            string Title = Request.Form.Get("SrNo");
            string Oasid = Request.Form.Get("Name");
            string keyword = Request.Form.Get("Photo");

            HttpFileCollectionBase attachFiles = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                attachFiles = Request.Files[0];

            foreach(file in attachFiles)
            {
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
```

Hopefully its helpful for you.